# OAuth2 to Google Drive with AccountManager in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get auth token with AccountManager in Android for Google Drive:

```
    String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

    GoogleAccountManager accountManager = credential.getGoogleAccountManager();
    accountManager.getAccountManager().getAuthToken(
                    credential.getSelectedAccount(),        // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType("com.google")
                    AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE,                        // Auth Token Type
                    null,                                   // Authenticator-specific options
                    this,                                   // Your activity
                    new OnTokenAcquired(),                  // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
                    new Handler(new OnAuthTokenError()));   // Callback called if an error occurs
```

And I get error code from logcat:

```
01-07 11:03:13.454 I/GLSUser ( 4608): GLS error: **INVALID_LANGUAGE** xxxx@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
01-07 11:03:13.454 V/GoogleLoginService( 4608): Returning error intent with: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity}
```

I don't quite get it why it indicates "INVALID_LANGUAGE" here, anyone gets ideas? Thanks.